# how to fetch data from HTML tags which i am getting as a string?

Tags: php, curl, rss

this is my code , I want to fetch data of title and description tag innerhtml..

```
$ch = curl_init() or die(curl_error());
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $linkurl);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            $data1 = curl_exec($ch);



$dom = new DOMDocument();
        @$dom->loadHTML($data1);//$dom=null string here
        //var_dump($data1);
        $meta = $dom->getElementsByTagName("meta");
        foreach ($meta as $node) {
            //echo $node->getAttribute('name');
            if ($node->getAttribute('name') == "Description") {  // not coming inside this loop
                $description = $node->getAttribute('content');
            }
}
curl_close($ch);
```

well i am getting html page from given url like php.net by using `curl=>$data1(string)`. and now i want selected data from that page like description and title of any website....

but when i do `var_dump($data1) returns=>string(42347)`""... i am not getting how to fetch data from that tags because it can be any url(website).

Comment: i need to fetch data from $data1 and wanted to get the data from tag (title and description)at one stroke. $linkurl=any url...

Comment: @ Muhammad Zeeshan, empty string is coming at var_dump($meta)    object(DOMNodeList)#2 (0)  { }

Comment: @ Gordon, sorry i but i am getting empty string there.....

Comment: no, you're not. It says object(DOMNodeList)#2 (0) and that's obviously not an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a native function for fetching the meta tags from a web page

- [`get_meta_tags` — Extracts all meta tag content attributes from a file and returns an array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php)

So you dont need cURL, nor DOM. And if you need to fetch other elements than the meta elements, you still dont need cURL, because DOM can load XML/HTML from remote locations as well with `load()` and `loadHTMLFile()`. Also, dont use error suppression, but `libxml_use_internal_errors(true)`.

Comment: @Brijesh then you are either doing something wrong or there is no meta data in the page.